# Как создать Snackbar?

Tags: java, android, activity, snackbar

Меня интересует как сделать так чтобы работало Snackbar.make...?(я создавал empty activity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас пустая активность то есть несколько вариантов как показать snackBar: независимо от условия показывать сообщение сразу же как запускается активность, либо добавить в xml какой-то виджет, например кнопку,и при нажатии на нее показывать snackBar, либо добавить какие-то условия, например если текущая дата равна какой-то определенной дате. Сам shackBar можно показать так:
добавляем например кнопку в xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLICK"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

дальше в активности в методе клика кнопки создаем сообщение и выводим его при нажатии на кнопку:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void onClick(View view){
        Snackbar.make(view, "Hello Android 5", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

вот [документация](https://material.io/develop/android/components/snackbar/) и [пример использования](https://javadevblog.com/primer-ispol-zovaniya-snackbar-v-android-sozdaem-kastomny-j-snackbar.html).

Comment: Странно я два дня назад тоже так пытался сделать... Вобщем у меня красным подчеркивало потому-что я не импортировал класс. Спасибо за ответ)